# "glib.h" not found on macOSX Ventura

Tags: c, macos, compiler-errors, clang

I am trying to build qemu for esp target using the command ninja -C build. I am getting error while finding the standard libraries on macOS. I think I am missing some kind of addition to the PATH variable but I dont know what. I have tried multiple possible solutions available on the web but None seem to help.

```
> ninja -C build
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[4/1471] Compiling C object tests/plugin/libsyscall.dylib.p/syscall.c.o
FAILED: tests/plugin/libsyscall.dylib.p/syscall.c.o
cc -Itests/plugin/libsyscall.dylib.p -Itests/plugin -I../tests/plugin -I../include/qemu -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.74.5/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.74.5/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.74.5/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre2/10.42/include -fcolor-diagnostics -Wall -Winvalid-pch -std=gnu11 -O0 -g -iquote . -iquote /Users/flying_raijin/espressif/qemu -iquote /Users/flying_raijin/espressif/qemu/include -iquote /Users/flying_raijin/espressif/qemu/tcg/aarch64 -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wno-initializer-overrides -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-string-plus-int -Wno-typedef-redefinition -Wno-tautological-type-limit-compare -Wno-psabi -Wno-gnu-variable-sized-type-not-at-end -fstack-protector-strong -MD -MQ tests/plugin/libsyscall.dylib.p/syscall.c.o -MF tests/plugin/libsyscall.dylib.p/syscall.c.o.d -o tests/plugin/libsyscall.dylib.p/syscall.c.o -c ../tests/plugin/syscall.c
../tests/plugin/syscall.c:13:10: fatal error: 'glib.h' file not found
#include <glib.h>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[5/1471] Compiling C object tests/plugin/libmem.dylib.p/mem.c.o
FAILED: tests/plugin/libmem.dylib.p/mem.c.o
cc -Itests/plugin/libmem.dylib.p -Itests/plugin -I../tests/plugin -I../include/qemu -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.74.5/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.74.5/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.74.5/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre2/10.42/include -fcolor-diagnostics -Wall -Winvalid-pch -std=gnu11 -O0 -g -iquote . -iquote /Users/flying_raijin/espressif/qemu -iquote /Users/flying_raijin/espressif/qemu/include -iquote /Users/flying_raijin/espressif/qemu/tcg/aarch64 -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wno-initializer-overrides -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-string-plus-int -Wno-typedef-redefinition -Wno-tautological-type-limit-compare -Wno-psabi -Wno-gnu-variable-sized-type-not-at-end -fstack-protector-strong -MD -MQ tests/plugin/libmem.dylib.p/mem.c.o -MF tests/plugin/libmem.dylib.p/mem.c.o.d -o tests/plugin/libmem.dylib.p/mem.c.o -c ../tests/plugin/mem.c
../tests/plugin/mem.c:13:10: fatal error: 'glib.h' file not found
#include <glib.h>
         ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: And did you install glib with homebrew or whatever package system you're using?

Comment: glib is not a standard library on macOS, or pretty much anywhere else. https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Mac

Comment: Yes, I have made sure that glib is installed on my machine.


_arch -x86_64 brew reinstall glib_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was with hombrew.
It seems when I migrated my Mac from intel to M1, the hombrew got copied at `/usr/local/bin` but the expected path for hombrew on Mac is `/opt/hombrew/bin`.

I uninstalled hombrew using https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew

and then reinstalled hombrew using https://github.com/homebrew/install#install-homebrew-on-macos-or-linux
and then I was successfully able to build qemu.